# I want to have a light/lampshade hanging from a cable component, but when running the level the mesh and light fall to the ground

Tags: unreal, unreal-5

Here's a screenshot illustrating my setup:

[image]

There is a cable component with attach start, want toand the cable itself swings fine. However I want to attach the cone to the floating end of the cable. I attempted to do this by adding a socket to the mesh:

[image]

As per the first pic I completed the "Attach End To" of the cable component, setting the Referenced Actor and Attach to Socket properties to my lampshade mesh and socket.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed it.

I had the lamp shade as the parent of the group, not the cable component. I reorganised it like this:

[image]